# White screens when switching to application

Tags: 12.04, unity, nvidia, graphics

Sometimes when I alt-tab between applications, the application will just be a white screen. This has happened with terminal and with firefox. I can fix the problem and get the program to render by maximizing or minimizing it.

I am using Unity-3D and my graphics cards is a GeForce GTX 460.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Unity?

Comment: Yes, I am using Unity 3D!

Comment: Okay. Then please also specify what graphics card or graphics hardware you're using, since that might be related. Note that you can edit this information into your question.

Comment: Am using Geforce GTX 460.

Comment: Did you installed proprietary drivers for the graphics card!??

Comment: Yes. I installed the ones off of Geforce website.

Comment: Try updating drivers.